# How to turn off scientifc notation when using char command in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I want to convert a polynomial expression into an array of characters
in MATLAB. We are using the command char. On my computer, char will change the format of the coefficients of a polynomial to scientific notation.

For example,

> char(x^2 + 0.0001*x)

will output $x^2 +1e-4\cdot x$ as an array of chars. That will generate an error in my program.

Can we get an array which contains $x^2+0.0001\cdot x$ of length $12$ instead of an array containing $x^2+1e-4\cdot x$ which is of length $10$ by using char? If there is a way of turning off the scientific notation in MATLAB, that will be great!

Thanks!

Comment: `char(x^2 + 0.0001*x)` does not return `x^2 +1e-4*x`, it returns the char that corresponds to the value of $x^2+0.0001x$. Do you simply want the string `x^2+0.0001*x`? Then just write `'x^2+0.0001*x'`.

Comment: It returns an array of chars. x^2 + 0.0001*x is a symbolic expression which has no value. x is a variable defined by syms x. This is an example, I would like to do that for any input polynomial f by char(f）.

Comment: Do you use `syms x` or what? And then `char(x^2 + 0.0001*x)` returns the $1$ by $10$ array of chars `x^2+1e-4*x`?

Comment: Yes, I use syms x, and it returns  1 by 10 array of chars x^2+1e-4*x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try converting your symbolic expression to variable precision arithmetic using [`vpa`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html) before using `char`:

```
syms x;
y = x^2 + 0.0001*x;
char(vpa(y))
```

See the [documentation for `vpa`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html) and for [`digits`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/digits.html) for how to adjust the conversion.